# Access the database by connection string

Tags: powershell-extensions

Context: I am trying to automate a few steps in the existing `Sitecore 10.1.1` environment using Sitecore PowerShell.

Problem: We have a command `Get-Database` to access the database either by providing the database name or the item. In my scenario, I need to access the database by providing the connection string.

Do we have a way?

Comment: https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/database-access-within-powershell

Answer (score 1):

The ISE includes a sample snippet SQL script.

```
Import-Function -Name Invoke-SqlCommand

$connection = [Sitecore.Configuration.Settings]::GetConnectionString("master")

$query = @"
SELECT TOP (10) *
  FROM [dbo].[Items]
"@
$records = Invoke-SqlCommand -Connection $connection -Query $query
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the database details using this way by passing the connection string.

```
# Using $AppPath you will get your application folder path
# Then append the path of connectionstring.config
$path = $AppPath + 'App_Config\ConnectionStrings.config'

# Get the content of this file
$content = [xml](Get-Content -Path $path)

# Give your connection string to read the node
$content.SelectSingleNode("connectionStrings/add[@connectionString='Data Source=RP-INTUNE-5VUYB\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=Sitecore10.1_Core;User ID=coreuser;Password=uiFxkSw6tlyKaScBgZre']")
```

This will give you the output of your connection string like this.

[image]

Now if you want to read the connection string name then you need to get the value in a variable like this.

```
$connectionString = $content.SelectSingleNode("connectionStrings/add[@connectionString='Data Source=RP-INTUNE-5VUYB\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=Sitecore10.1_Core;User ID=coreuser;Password=uiFxkSw6tlyKaScBgZre']")
```

And then get your connection string name.

```
Write-Host $connectionString.name
```

You will get this.

[image]

Comment: This won't work if the settings are under Configuration for the Azure App. The application is hosted in Azure PAAS.